# Mapping processing doesn't work using Nextflow scripting language

Tags: shell, mapping, pipeline, nextflow

I'm on a Linux virtual-machine and I have installed Nextflow, created directories for the input files: index.ref and fastq and create a pipeline.nf script.

Here below the code:

```
#!bin/env nextflow

params.index_dir="/mountpoint/nextflow_container/BWAIndex"
params.ref="/mountpoint/nextflow_container/BWAIndex/human_g1k_v37_decoy.fasta"
params.fastq="/mountpoint/nextflow_container/fastq/ALL_*_{1,2}*"


process mapping {

input:
path index_dir
val ref
tuple val(sample_id), path(fastq)

output:
path "${sample_id}.sorted.bam"

script:

"""

bwa mem -t 2 ${ref} ${fastq}  -o ${sample_id}.bam

"""

}

workflow {

index_ch=Channel.fromPath(params.index_dir)
ref_ch=Channel.of(params.ref)
fastq_ch=Channel.fromFilePairs(params.fastq)

mapping(index_ch, ref_ch, fastq_ch)
mapping.out.view()

}
```

The results prints out:
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.04.4
Launching `pipeline.nf` [distracted_dijkstra] DSL2 - revision: 16e98f914c
executor >  local (1)
[b9/c05177] process > mapping (1) [  0%] 0 of 1

And it doesn't go on.

Someone knows why this happen?

Comment: Can you attach your `.nextflow.log` file? Try running `nextflow -trace nextflow run pipeline.nf`. This way, the log file will have more information about what is happening. Based on your script alone, nothing seems weird to me. Just for safety, I would `.view()` all channels to make sure they contain what you expect them to.

Comment: Also, are you running this on a local machine? It may be fairly slow if your machine isn't that fast. Regardless, if you have large bam files and a large reference genome, mapping can take a dozen hours or more. How long did you wait? There is no error indicated, so I don't think nextflow or bwa are making mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

All looks fine here, seems that all you need is some patience. Its hard to say anything more without `.nextflow.log`.

- It might take hours depending on file size. Most likely process is running. Apart from log, you can open the second terminal and have a look at the CPU/mem usage (use e.g. `top` or `htop`). You will see lot of CPU usage with BWA.
- Channels should be fine (otherwise you will not have `[0%] 0 of 1` or end up with error). Use `.view()` to verify
- Also, make sure resources are optimized. Adjust `memory` and most importantly `cpus` - see [documentation](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#cpus).
- You can also `cd` to workdir of this process (something like `/work/b9/c05177...`), check logs, see if your expected files are there, check exact command executed, try to run it "outside" of the pipeline